# Showing the vector field $(f(x+y),f(x+y))$ is conservative for continuous $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$

Tags: vector-analysis, vector-fields

This is the question:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. Prove that the vector field $F : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $F(x, y) := (f(x + y), f(x + y) )$ is conservative.

My attempt was this: A field is conservative if $\oint_C F\cdot dl= 0$ for any simple closed curve. I took C an arbitrary simple closed curve, so $F$ follows the green's Theorem, then the line integral is
$$\oint_{\partial D}F\cdot dl=\iint_D\frac{\partial f(x+y)}{y}-\frac{\partial f(x+y)}{x}$$

and I only get up here, my professor suggest that use the Schwarz's theorem, but I'm not pretty sure if i can use it, because I know that F is continuous because is continuous component by component, but I'm not sure that the derivative is also continuous or either exists, so I'm stuck with that

i appreciate any suggestions or some help with this exercise

Comment: If $f$ is only continuous, not necessarily differentiable, then you can't use Green's theorem.

Comment: why? Is my first time with this topic ;C

Comment: Note that this field is "one-dimensional" in a sense—all points along the lines $x+y = c$ map to the same vector, which is perpendicular to those lines—so you can only return to your starting point by going effectively back the way you came. This idea needs to be formalized, of course. Possible approach: A conservative vector field is the gradient of what?

Comment: Because Green's theorem uses the derivative of $f$. You can't use that if it doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach dosen't work as you don't know if $f$ is even differentiable, so Green's theorem cannot apply.

One approach is to define the antiderivative
$$ \varphi(x,y) = \int_0^{x+y} f(t) \ dt \, , $$
which is well defined as $f$ is continuous.
Then according to the Fundamental Thm. of Calculus (or the Leibniz integral rule), $\partial \varphi/\partial x = f(x+y) = \partial \varphi/\partial y$. It follows that your vector field $F = \nabla \varphi$, and hence is conservative.